# Why can I not load a module using a string in a variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, module

The follow will successfully load the module using `import('test')` but not the second example. They are running in an Angular 9 application using the default Webpack configuration.

```
var testModuleName = 'test';
import('test').then(o => console.log('I loaded test from string'));
import(testModuleName).then(o => console.log('I loaded test from var'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack has to know at least part of location from where to import module at build time. This is required for bundling. For example:

```
const inputComponent = 'dropdown'
import(`./inputs/${inputComponent}.component`)
```

In this case it would work, but everything in `inputs` directory would be added to bundle, even if `inputComponent` is const.
This way you lose treeshaking.

You can also filter what will be included into bundle by using *Magic Comments*:

```
const inputComponent = 'dropdown'
import(
    /* webpackExclude: REGEX OF FILE NAMES TO EXCLUDE */
    `./inputs/${inputComponent}.component`
)
```

You can read more about how webpack processes modules [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods).